# Shell script: Check that file is file and not directory

Tags: bash, file, shell, directory

I'm currently working on a small cute shell script to loop through a specific folder and only output the files inside it, excluding any eventual directories. Unfortunately I can't use `find` as I need to access the filename variables.

Here's my current snippet, which doesn't work:

```
for filename in "/var/myfolder/*"
do
  if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    echo $filename # Is file!
  fi

done;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not escape /var/myfolder/*, meaning, you must remove the double-quotes in order for the expression to be correctly expanded by the shell into the desired list of file names.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is not using `find`. The filename can be retrieved by using `{}`.

```
find /var/myfolder -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without double quotes around /var/myfolder/* (reason being is that by putting double quotes you are making all the files a single string instead of each filename a separate string

Comment: No, all the files are *not* a single string. It's make the asterisk literal and it doesn't get glob expanded.

Comment: You are right, it's a literal asterisk, which is then expanded in "echo $filename"

Answer (score 1):

`for filename in "/var/myfolder/*"`

The quotes mean you get one giant string from that glob -- stick an `echo _ $filename _` immediately before the `if` to discover that it only goes through the 'loop' once, with something that isn't useful.

Remove the quotes and try again :)

Comment: It's not a glob inside quotes. The asterisk is literal.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, thanks for the correction; I assumed because `echo` printed out the whole directory contents that the shell had expanded the asterisk before the assignment. I hadn't realized the shell would expand the asterisk when executing `echo` -- thanks for fixing my assumptions, twice wrong. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use find and avoid all these hassles.

```
for i in $(find /var/myfolder -type f)
do
echo $(basename $i)
done
```

Isn't this what you're trying to do with your situation? If you want to restrict depth, use the `-maxdepth` option to find.

Comment: Using `for` and `find` in that way will fail if there are filenames that include spaces. Use `find -exec` or `find -print0 | xargs -0` or `find | while IFS=$'\n' read -r` or `while IFS=$'\n' read -r ... done < <(find)`.